# How to add a request wise variable in httpcontext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

In HttpContext(Or some thing like this) I need to add a temperory variable from a controller which need to available through out the request processing(Request wise variable). But the HttpContext.Current.Request is readonly. If i'm adding in Items its not getting outside. How can i achieve this

Thanks & Regards
Binesh Nambiar C

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for [`HttpContext.Items`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a dictionary that can be used to store items for the duration of the current request. It goes out of scope at the end of the request.

```
// Set
HttpContext.Items["Customer"] = customer;

// Get
var customer = HttpContext.Items["Customer"];
```

Comment: I tried HttpContext.Current.Items. Its not working. I'm using the field now in a custom modelbinder

Comment: Could you provide more details what you are trying to achieve? (please edit your question and add them). Model binding happens near the beginning of the request, so it probably doesn't make much sense to get values from the request cache (although it might be a good place to set them).

Comment: BTW - You should never use the static `HttpContext.Current` in MVC (which might be your problem). In a model binder, the context object is passed in. You can access the request cache like `var cache = controllerContext.HttpContext.Items["Key"];`

Comment: Hi I Solved by adding to header of Request proprty